# Django - Success Message Mixin Does not work on Login

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to display a success message on login using the SuccessMessageMixin but the message is not displayed. Is there any reason why this would happen?

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
```

urls.py

```
from .views import HomeView, LoginFormView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', HomeView.as_view(), name = 'home'),
    path('login/', LoginFormView.as_view(), name = 'login'),
]
```

views.py

```
class HomeView(FormView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

class LoginFormView(auth_views.LoginView, SuccessMessageMixin):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    success_url = 'home/'
    success_message = "You were successfully logged in."
```

login.html

```
<h4>Login to your Account:</h4>
<div>
    <form action "" method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <button type = "submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

home.html

```
{% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            {{ message }}
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SuccessMessageMixin` needs to be **first** (or atleast before the generic view) in the order of inheritance, i.e. it should be `LoginFormView(SuccessMessageMixin, auth_views.LoginView)` instead of `LoginFormView(auth_views.LoginView, SuccessMessageMixin)`:

```python
class LoginFormView(SuccessMessageMixin, auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    success_url = 'home/'
    success_message = "You were successfully logged in."
```

Comment: Thanks. Also I appreciate the explanation!